# Is it advisable to run Visual Studio Tools for Office in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, exchange-server, nservicebus

I've received requirements to upgrade a legacy Outlook addin, which requires an active logged on user, to a standalone microservice (implemented using NServiceBus).

The goal of the addin is to monitor incoming emails (by communicating with the Exchange) that match certain pre-set criteria and *do stuff* with it.

> Is VSTO sufficiently robust to run inside a Windows Service?

- Is it sufficiently threadsafe?
- Could it lock up the mailbox, making it unreachable via human interaction?
- Could VSTO make the service crash?
- Even worse, could VSTO cause the Exchange to lock / crash?

*If any of these concerns are real, are there alternatives?*

Comment: How do you plan to use VSTO from a Service? If your talking about automation via the Office interfaces then that is absolutely not supported from a service and all your concerns (bar the last) apply.  Alternatives depend on what you want to do with Exchange.

Comment: I asked about VSTO because that's what is used now. If there are better alternatives to run as a service, than by all means.

Comment: I do not know about Exchange but for sure VSTO plugin can crush Outlook. Also I do not think it is possible to run VSTO plugin inside Win Service.

Comment: May be this can help with your goals: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

Comment: @Nick That looks interesting, I'll look into it!

Comment: EWS is definitely the way to go here, as @Nick says. Note that basic authentication for EWS is soon to be deprecated, so make sure you start out using oauth in this new project. Depending on what you’re doing, the MS graph endpoints might also cater to your needs.

Comment: @sasfrog We're on AD, that would be preferred, or do I -need- to use OAUTH? That's also possible, we have an Identity Server running ...

Comment: Ah maybe I’ve mis-spoken, I’m not sure about on-premises Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it not advisable to run VSTO within a windows service. Writing something in VSTO is useful for its UI components, presenting something to the user, interacting with the user, and would mean you would need to start an instance of Outlook for your add-in to load. Installing Office on the server is typically frowned upon, create problems when used in a multi-threaded way, and create problems most developers are unprepared to handle.

There are also other avenues you might want to explore, so instead of using the Outlook library directly you can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) via the EWS Managed API, or if you are not on-prem, go with the REST or Graph API.

Comment: happen to have link to those API's? not sure which you are talking about.

Comment: The EWS Managed API might be your best choice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange

Comment: Microsoft Graph is suggested over the REST API,: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview

Comment: I don't have any good code sources for you, but to give you some background, I am currently replacing Outlook VSTO add-ins with ones built on the Office JS API, essentially creating the add-in from HTML, JS, and CSS. The issue that I've run into are limitations in the API - the inability to handle async results larger than 1 Mb, and inability to do cross domain transactions via EWS - such that I will likely be creating a service in MVC to handle EWS via the EWS Managed API. The managed API can be done is C#/VB.